# Does CKeditor 5 have support for content templates?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I was looking to upgrade to CKEDITOR 5, but I was going through the documentation and did not see any support for content templates.  I wanted to see if I was just missing something and if there is any support for this kind of feature in ckeditor5 or if I would need to stick with ckeditor4 for this feature?

Example:
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: There is general support and a commercial plugin `templates`. About the usage of own templates I found this manual: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/tutorials/widgets/implementing-a-block-widget.html

Answer (score 0):

CKEditor 5 is a complete rewrite, so any plugins also need to be completely rewritten. So far, the Content Template plugin doesn't exist for CKEditor5.

However there is a feature request: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/1585

And potential that Drupal developers will work on a replacement: https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor_templates/issues/3273358#comment-14817501

Answer (score -1):

Maybe not! Sad! I checked in CKEDitor5. There is no information.